# How to add tag to task using the asana API?

Tags: curl, asana

I am attempting to add a tag to a task using the following curl command as per the API:

```
curl -u <api_key>: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/<task_id>/addTag -u "tag=<tag_id>"
```

When running the command I am prompted for a password and then get an error:

```
Enter host password for user 'tag=<tag_id>':
{"errors":[{"message":"Not Authorized"}]}
```

Actual values in <> are suppressed.

I got various read end-points to work correctly, but 'addTag' is not behaving as expected.  Here is the documentation:

https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tags

Anybody successfully using this end-point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the docs (should be fixed since) - the `-u` flag is for user, the `-d` flag is for data. Try again, but with `-d "tag=<tag_id>"`?